# Generate dynamic drop down with options from an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my view file I've one button. I want to append drop down on click of button.
Here is my code:

**Controller File**

```
$scope.appendnewrow = function (result) {
  var tr = '<select><option ng-repeat="'+site in
  result+'">'+site.name+'</option></select>';
  var temp = $compile(tr)($scope);
  angular.element(document.getElementById('123')).append(temp);
}
```

**View File**

```
<a ng-click="appendnewrow(result)">Add domain</a>
```

When I ran this code options did not populate.

Comment: try encapsulating the function in $scope.$apply(function(){
})

Comment: @bhanu.cs Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the *Angular way* do to that.

Considering your data is in `$scope.result`, you can display the array using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<a ng-click="addRow(row)">Add domain</a>
<select ng-options="site as site.name for site in result"></select>
```

Add this function in your controller:

```
$scope.addRow = function(newRow) {
    $scope.result.push(newRow);
}
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/ebv6uvhw/) of what it could looks like.

Comment: No I don't want select tag in my view file.